# Importacion de archivos externos js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

Estoy teniendo un problema a la hora de importar unos archivos js esenciales para que funcione la plantilla Core UI.
Cuando incluyo mis archivos css en la etiqueta style de mi componente App.vue funcionan bien(me muestra en el navegador la plantilla) pero cuando importo los archivos js de la plantilla(jquery, bootstrap.min.js, popper js, pace js) no me muestran ningun error al ejecutar npm run dev pero al ver el navegador no me carga nada de nada, un fondo gris aparece nada mas.
ESTOY USANDO SINGLE FILE COMPONENT
Dejo mi codigo de importacion en mi componente:

```
<script>
import '../static/css/style.css'
import '../static/css/simple.css'

import '../static/js/bootstrap.min.js'
import '../static/js/Chart.min.js'
import '../static/js/jquery.min.js'
import '../static/js/popper.min.js'
import '../static/js/template.js'
</script>
```

Las rutas relativas estan bien, no entiendo porque hay problema con los archivos js

Comment: Bootstrap se incluye automaticamente si usas bootstrap vue. jquery esta incluido por defecto. Donde estas poniendo esta etiqueta script? y como esta armado tu proyecto?

Comment: @gbianchi Esta estiqueta script es parte de mi componente App.vue, estoy usando single file components.

Comment: App.vue no puede contener una etiqueta script, por eso te preguntaba.. directamente la ignora... Eso deberia estar en el html que contiene a tu aplicacion VUE

Comment: @gbianchi Todo componente .vue está dividido en tres partes: style, template y script. ¿A qué te refieres con que "ignora" la etiqueta script?

Comment: Esa etiqueta script es donde va el componente VUE, no donde se importan los js que vos estas buscando importar.

Answer (score 1):

Para *JQuery* y *Bootstrap* se hace así:

```
import * as jquery from '../static/js/jquery.min.js'
import * as bootstrap from '../static/js/bootstrap.min.js'
```

En tus archivos *JS* deberías tener declarado export default.

Por ejemplo:

```
export default {
    text: 'Estoy exportando un objeto',
    template: `...`
}
```

Y ese sí lo puedes importar así:

```
import '../static/js/template.js'
```

Answer (score 1):

Para importar archivos JS debes añadir un atributo a la etiqueta script:

```
<script type="module">
    /* JavaScript module code here */
    import * as modulo from '/modules/my-module.js';
</script>
```

Espero que te sirva.